# Ubuntu freezes on login after nvidia-prime intel

Tags: ubuntu, nvidia, intel-graphics

I have an Asus GL553 with Intel 560 and Nvidia GTX 1050 and I'm tried to configure my hybrid cards with nvidia-prime.
I installed Ubuntu Gnome 17.04 then installed nvidia-381 and ran prime-select intel I had to hard reboot and when I tried to login the system freezes.
I have researched and read all these topics but I can't find a solution.

https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/991853/complete-freeze-with-nvidia-prime/?offset=8
https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/991853/complete-freeze-with-nvidia-prime/?offset=18
https://askubuntu.com/questions/831928/edited-to-shutdown-hangs-on-intel-grapics-on-16-04-with-4-7-2-kernel
https://askubuntu.com/questions/879856/nvidia-prime-cant-switch-to-intel
https://bugs.launchpad.net/lightdm/+bug/1637733
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-prime/+bug/1663926

Has anyone could configure nvidia properly?

Comment: Try loading the a newer release of the nvidia driver?

Comment: version 381 is the last release

Comment: Specifically 381.22 (dated 9 May 2017) is the latest release according to the NVIDIA website.

Comment: Yup, thats the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally did it.

1.- Make a folder to store the SSDT files. Then extract it from the ACPI tables (run this part as root):

```
# mkdir dsdt
# cd dsdt
# SSDT_FILES=`ls /sys/firmware/acpi/tables/ | grep SSDT`
# for file in $SSDT_FILES ; do cat "/sys/firmware/acpi/tables/$file" > "$file.dat"; done
# cat /sys/firmware/acpi/tables/DSDT > DSDT.dat
```

2.- Make sure you have IASL installed. On ubuntu, sudo `apt install iasl` should suffice. I downloaded the source and compiled it myself to get the latest version, but I don't think thats necessary.

3.- There's a duplicate definition in one SSDT file which won't let us dissassemble it. Find out which one it is and delete it:

```
# grep PRT0 *.dat
Binary file DSDT.dat matches
Binary file SSDT1.dat matches
# mv SSDT1.dat SSDT1.bak
```

So in my case it is SSDT1. Replace it with whatever you get. Do not touch DSDT.dat

4.- Next, we find the SSDT file with the code we need to change. We look for the file with both "NVID" and "OSYS" are present: (There's probably a better way to do this in grep)

```
# grep NVID *.dat
Binary file SSDT10.dat matches
Binary file SSDT3.dat matches
# grep OSYS SSDT10.dat
# grep OSYS SSDT3.dat
Binary file SSDT3.dat matches
```

So in my case it was SSDT3, if its different you replace all further instances of SSDT3 with whatever you get.

5.- Disassemble!

```
# iasl -e *.dat -d SSDT3.dat
```

6.- Hopefully you don't see any errors at this point. Replace all instances of OSYS except the declaration with the constant for Windows 7, and bump the definition block number by one:

```
# sed -i '/^ *External/! s/OSYS/0x07D9/g' SSDT3.dsl
# sed -i '/^ *DefinitionBlock/ s/0x00001000/0x00001001/g' SSDT3.dsl
```

If you have a different BIOS, the Definition Block number might not be 1000. Just open SSDT3.dsl in a text editor and look for DefinitionBlock. Whatever number you see on that line, increment it by one.

7.- Compile everything and hope there are no errors.

```
# iasl -ve -tc -p SSDT3 SSDT3.dsl
```

8.- Make an image:

```
# mkdir -p kernel/firmware/acpi
# cp SSDT3.aml kernel/firmware/acpi/ssdt3.aml
# find kernel | cpio -H newc --create > acpi_gpufix
```

8.- All the following instructions corresponding to Ubuntu and GRUB2. Copy it to the boot folder. the initrd.img it's your default img from boot folder:

```
# cp acpi_gpufix /boot/
```

you can permanently add it to your GRUB by editing /etc/grub.d/10_linux. I had to change the line `initrd ${rel_dirname}/${initrd}` to `initrd ${rel_dirname}/acpi_gpufix ${rel_dirname}/${initrd}`. Then run update-grub2.

9.- To check if it works:

```
$ dmesg | grep ACPI | grep override
[    0.000000] ACPI: Table Upgrade: override [SSDT-PegSsd- PegSsdt]
[    0.000000] ACPI: SSDT 0x000000007A715080 Physical table override, new table: 0x0000000079493000
```

Now you can change the GPU wihtout freezes

source:

https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/issues/764#issuecomment-306543064
https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1012369/linux/laptop-freezes-changing-video-cards